# How can I get the ndb.Model when my only input is an ndb.Query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Let's say there is `ndb.Model` that looks like this:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
  bar = ndb.StringProperty()
```

My question is, if my only input is the `Foo.query()` how can I get the model as an object that this query belongs to?

```
def query_to_model(query):
  # some magic 
  return model
```

---

The `Foo.query().kind` return the model's name as a string, but I didn't manage to find a way to get it as an object.

The following works using `eval`, but only when the model is defined in the same file:

```
def query_to_model(query):
  return eval(query.kind)
```

I want something more general than that.

Comment: query.get().key.kind() ? I'm not sure..

Comment: Have you heard of `Polymodel`? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

Comment: @presveva It's equivalent to query.kind, just returns the kind as a string which is not good for me..

Comment: @bossylobster Yes I've heard of Polymodel.. what about them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have imported code with this model definition, the list `ndb.Model._kind_map` should contain it. Here is the magic:

```
def query_to_model(query):
  return ndb.Model._kind_map[query.name]
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to find the model class if you have the kind name:

```
model_module = KIND_MODULES(kind_name)
mod = __import__(model_module, globals(), locals(), [kind_name], -1)
model_class = getattr(mod, kind_name)
```

The KIND Modules dict holds the modules to import the models from:

```
KIND_MODULES = { 'Users' : 'models', 'Comments' : 'models', 'Cities' : 'examples.models' }
```

Comment: Greg's answer is more elegant and you don't need to keep a dict with your models..

Comment: It is not documented. But Guido also used it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731433/following-backreferences-of-unknown-kinds-in-ndb