# Google Appengine DB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Since couple of weeks have i write operations that are not executed or read operations which don't find the objects in the DB.

It worked perfectly before. Is there a known problem by google?

Here is my code:

```
String query = "name==" + "\"" + name + "\"";
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
List<UserAddresses> result = null;
try {
    Query q = (Query) pm.newQuery(UserAddresses.class);
    q.setFilter(query);
    result = (List<UserAddresses>) q.execute();                          
    q.closeAll();                          
    if (result != null)
        return result.get(0).getAddressesArray();
    logger.severe("UserAddresses not found");
    return null;
}catch (Exception e) {throw e;} 
finally {pm.close();   }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not running into eventual consistency behaviour. Are you doing queries for the entities or get by key ?

Comment: For the save, i'm updating an existing entity using persist. Reading is now described in the post.

Comment: I don't use java, but you are performing a query so you may well be experiencing eventual consistency. Retrieve the entity by it's key rather than a query to confirm the update has occurred, or perform an ancestor query if the entity has a parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the ndb.Model when my only input is an ndb.Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651975/how-can-i-get-the-ndb-model-when-my-only-input-is-an-ndb-query)