# What's the alternative to back-reference property in NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917569/google-app-engine-ndb-equivalent-for-modelname-set-backreference-property) and the simple and clear answer but it's not useful in my case because the answer don't consider the nested `for`. please, see the code:

```py
class SuperCat(ndb.Model):

class Category(ndb.Model):
  supercat = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=SuperCat)

class SubCat(ndb.Model):
  category = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Category)
```

handler:

```py
Categories = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE supercat = :1", supercat_key)
self.generate('supercat.html', {'Categories': Categories})
```

in template, with the old db.Model and the back-reference property this is enough:

```py
{{ for Category in Categories }}
  {{ for SubCat in Category.subcat_set }} # this is the back-reference in action
```

What is the equally simple alternative to serve such data structure?

Comment: seems that [Structured Properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) is a good start point..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at this systematically.  First, the [db->ndb translation guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit) tells us that the query returning SubCategory instances for a given Category instance is as follows:

```
  subcats_query = SubCategory.query(SubCategory.category == cat.key)
```

(Note that I use lowercase names for instances/entities and CapWords for classes/models.  So cat is a Category entity.)

So in Python, we would write your double loop as follows:

```
  for cat in categories:
    for subcat in SubCat.query(SubCat.category == cat.key):
      ...blah...
```

In order to turn this into something that's easily accessible from the template, let's define a new method on the Category class:

```
  class Category(ndb.Model):

    supercat = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=SuperCat)

    def subcat_set(self):
      return SubCat.query(SubCat.category == self.key)
```

Note that this is a method; in Python, you have to call it:

```
  for cat in categories:
    for subcat in cat.subcat_set():
      ...blah...
```

But in a template you can (must) leave out the () call syntax, so you get what you want:

```
  {{ for cat in categories }}
    {{ for subcat in cat.subcat_set }}
      ...blah...
```

Give it a try!

Comment: works! but only with () in template. without () i get a TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable.

Comment: What template system are you using? I thought Django auto-calls callables.  But maybe Jinja2 doesn't?  If you don't like the (), you can decorate the method with @property (lowercase 'p', a Python built-in).